# Is the restriction of analytic functions on smooth manifolds analytic?

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-functions

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a smooth manifold. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ be an analytic function.

I wonder if the restriction $f|_M$ is analytic?

My motivation to write this question is to understand the embedding theorem from Whitney which states that a differentiable manifold can be smoothly embedded in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence some people claims (without proof ) that $M$ admits an analytic structure.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that an analytic function on some domain $D$ is going to be analytic at every point $x$ with an open neighbourhood wholly contained in $D$ (by definition, radius of convergence, etc.). So, I'm not sure what the problem is (but I don't know anything about manifolds)

Comment: The function $f$ is analytic on an open set  $U \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ but it is not clear to me that $f$ should be analytic in $M \cap U$ since $M \cap U$  might not have a non-empty interior in $\mathbb{R}^N$  .

Comment: What does it mean for a function on a manifold to be analytic? Wouldnt that require an analytic atlas as well?

Comment: I am trying to understand the embedding theorem from Whitney which states that a differential manifold can be smoothly embedded in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Hence some people claims (without proof ) that $M$ admits an analytic structure.

Comment: If you use an arbitrary analytic structure on $M$ (compatible with the smooth structure), then, of course, the restriction need not be analytic.

Comment: Is it possible to have an analytic structure on $M$ such that the restriction is analytic?

Comment: @jaogye No, but you should update the question to make it clear that this is what you are asking.